# Convert Nodejs JSON object to List<String>

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am new to NodeJS - I am doing this in a AWS lambda function and have the below JSON object

```
{
  "subnetsToUse": [
    {
      "subnetId": "subnet-0g6e5ad78f2841dc9"        },
    {
      "subnetId": "subnet-089e0d4de075664b3"        },
    {
      "subnetId": "subnet-06778539a55adc513"        }
  ]
}
```

I need to return a list of subnetIds from this.

```
subnet-0g6e5ad78f2841dc9,subnet-0g6e5ad78f2841dc9,subnet-0g6e5ad78f2841dc9
```

Here is what I have tried so far

```
var objectKeysArray = Object.keys(subnetsToUse) 
objectKeysArray.forEach(function(subnetId) 
{ var objValue = subnetsToUse[subnetId] })
```

How do I achieve this in NodeJS.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I have tried this -   `var objectKeysArray = Object.keys(subnetsToUse)
            objectKeysArray.forEach(function(subnetId) {
                var objValue = subnetsToUse[subnetId]
            })` and it returns empty

Comment: [Edit] the question to give a [mre]. But why *wouldn't* it? forEach doesn't return anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am sorry I did not get what is wrong with my code. Can you explain, please?

Comment: Why did you not put your code in the question? Read [mre] again: input, code, output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Array.map` or `Array.reduce` to iterate over the object values and push them into an array for example.

```js
const data = {
  "subnetsToUse": [
    {
      "subnetId": "subnet-0g6e5ad78f2841dc9",
      "availabilityZone": "us-west-2c"
    },
    {
      "subnetId": "subnet-089e0d4de075664b3",
      "availabilityZone": "us-west-2b"
    },
    {
      "subnetId": "subnet-06778539a55adc513",
      "availabilityZone": "us-west-2a"
    }
  ]
}


const mapRes = data.subnetsToUse.map((currentValue) => {
  return currentValue.subnetId;
});

console.log("mapRes", mapRes)


const reduceRes = data.subnetsToUse.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  accumulator.push(currentValue.subnetId);
  return accumulator;
}, []);


console.log("reduceRes",reduceRes)
```